# Add icon in navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer and i want to add icon. But i dont know how to implement it. Is there any way i can customize my list inside navigation drawer? and use menu instead of array for items inside the navigation drawer. Thanks in advance :)

Heres my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new One()).commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
     }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    fragmentClass = One.class;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragmentClass = Two.class;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment

            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
           mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });


         }

      private void setupDrawer() {
      mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
     // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

    @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

Comment: The List you use inside Drawer can be customized just like a normal listView, what is the hurdle?

Comment: There is also a dedicated design library class for this now. If you are creating a new App, implementing the design library might save you time. [Official blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Comment: Thanks for this @Knossos, but im using sdk 22.0.0 and when im trying to add the support design library im getting an error . how can i add that library ?

Comment: That depends on the error.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your navigation Drawer xml file add menu file `app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

in activity_main_drawer menu file define your icons wrt their names

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Camera" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Manage" />
    </group>
```

In your MainActivity.java call the action of each item click of drawer menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
                      // Call your Action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                      // Call your Action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
                       // Call your Action
           }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just create your custom layout for drawer list item. 
Check answer f.e. here [How to add icons to items in a navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667380/how-to-add-icons-to-items-in-a-navigation-drawer)

In your case you have to create your own adapter instead of ArrayAdapter and your custom item list view, that will contain ImageView for icon.